# Ubuntu 20.04 Crashes After 12-18 hours consistently. Can't figure out why

Tags: 20.04, crash

I am relatively new to Linux, running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop on a Ryzen 9 5650X. . I access the machine from my Windows 10 desktop via XRDP. It seems, without fail, after a decent period of uptime (12-18 hours), the system crashes.

Symptoms are I maximize the remote desktop window, and nothing responds, then within 5 or 10 seconds, the xrdp session disconnects. Even if I plug monitor and keyboard directly in, there is no video output. Hitting the tower's reset button reboots the machine and everything is back to normal again until it happens again. This has been consistent for the past week and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why.

Here are the results from `journalctl -b -1 -e`:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZl7w.jpg)

I've read that X Server crashing is a common issue but I don't know how to confirm if that is the issue or not. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Running desktop version.

Comment: You haven't said if you could reboot via keyboard commands direct to the kernel (ie. SysRq commands), as they'll work even if the GUI/X is dead.  Did you try? You didn't say if you're asking about a Server or Desktop install, or which stack you're using (server installs defaults to GA which can be changed at install, Ubuntu desktop defaults to HWE but that can be changed post-install).  If Xorg has crashed; SysRq keyboard commands wil work answering that question (but you skipped keyboard commands in your description).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for responding. It's desktop version and I don't know if any keyboard command work since this kills my remote connection. When it happens again, I will try SSH'ing into the system to see if I can still run commands. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: No I meant commands on the local keyboard.  Yes you can try a remote `ssh` connection, but it was direct commands on the local machine allowing you to bypass any GUI/X/sessions and give commands direct to the kernel (bypassing any user session/program be it dead/locked etc). They'll work even if all GUI/terminal sessions are dead.. the only reason it won't work is if the kernel has panic'd which you'll note on the local screen.. either way that's useful knowledge, but I'm betting kernel hasn't panic'd

Comment: OK, so computer completely locks up. No SysRq, no SSH, no remote. Any thoughts of where to continue investigating?

Comment: If it's kernel panic (ie. sysrq keys don't respond; you weren't specific as to what SysRq commands you tried; but I'll assume REISUB, REISUO & generally obvious commands) then I'd blame hardware due kernel panic.  I'd boot a *live* system of something else, have it run a day and start looking at hardware, test ram, cap scan, test psu disks etc... No SysRq response means it's not Ubuntu or GNU (or tweaks to OS but crash is hardware/kernel level), with hardware most likely (or corruption causing the panic). Local screen should have kernel panic crash evidence though (unless hardware at fault)

Comment: I am unable to try any sysrq because there is no video output and no power to keyboard/mouse when plugged directly into system after crashing.  Keep in mind, I'm remoted into this machine, so after it crashes, I try connecting a monitor and keyboard directly to it, but get nothing (though system still powered on, fans spinning, etc). I did run memtest over night, no errors. I'm stuck at how to identify the possible culprit since I don't have spare hardware to swap. Any specific places in the logs to look for clues? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: SysRq keys can only ever be executed on the local box; as if executed on a remote box they'll be treated as being a command for the local box (they aren't read by user level programs, so no user-level running program will see them and thus have any capacity to route it to a remote machine; they are reserved commands for direct-local-control .. they are how you send commands direct to the running kernel skipping any stuck GUI/UI etc).   You don't need a screen, as the machine response can usually be heard/seen on the box itself (even if *headless*) but you do need to be local.